# Receiving some string characters as ? characters from Postgres responses on a Rust sockets connection

Tags: postgresql, rust

I am using Rust to create a Postgres driver. When receiving raw Bytes from a socket connection how can I properly decode it? I am making a TcpStream call to Postgres and get back a type BytesMut. I do String::from_utf8_lossy(&bytes[..]) to decode it. But that gives me stuff like this

```
id����createdAt@updatedAt@userName@��6fullName@��hdescription@���region@��6mainUrl���avatar@   ������Dv        12023-10-22 00:18:44.6872023-10-22 00:18:44.687jon
SELECT 1ZI    1     | John JamesI am a developer������������C
```

I believe those ? symbols represent pipes, because when my text does not have pipes it seems to parse fine. But regardless what is the proper way to decode these strings so that I get back carriage returns, spaces, etc? I tried utf16, but that did not work either (parsed into chinese). For example when using psql I get nicely formatted text like this.

[image]

Comment: A "�" is the UTF-8 replacement character, which is used (by `from_utf8_lossy`) to replace bytes that are not valid UTF-8. This needs more details what exactly you are doing because this smells like you're using the binary protocol instead of a text-based protocol.

Comment: I'm modifying the pgcat code to learn. And yes you're right this is the binary protocol, because when I print the bytes I see stuff like this: b"T\0\0\0\xf3\0\tid\0\0\0@\x01\0\x01\0\0\0\x14\0\x08\xff\xff\xff\xff\0\0 ..." How should I be parsing this correctly?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like a [row-description](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html#PROTOCOL-MESSAGE-FORMATS-ROWDESCRIPTION) followed by a [data-row](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html#PROTOCOL-MESSAGE-FORMATS-DATAROW). The full documentation of the protocol is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html).

Comment: Ok now I'm starting to see thanks, but I'm very new to this. Are there any examples of Rust code that attempts to parse this binary syntax? Or even javascript code.

Comment: What does this have to do with websockets?

Comment: What makes you think that postgres replies with a single UTF-8 string? Notice that `psql` is a postgres client, parsing the protocol responses and doing its own formatting to the results, not just putting the response on the terminal (use `telnet` to do that).

Comment: "*I am using Rust to create a Postgres driver*" - why not use [an existing one](https://crates.io/crates/postgres)?

Comment: I agree with Bergi, *"I'm very new to this"* and *"I am using Rust to create a Postgres driver"* seem to be two statements that are not very compatible with one another. Why not use an existing driver? Writing your own driver without even knowing the difference between text-based answers and the binary protocol seems questionable ... Don't get me wrong, if you want to do it as a learning experience, go for it :) but I feel like this is one of those things that will become frustrating fast.

Comment: *"Are there any examples of Rust code that attempts to parse this binary syntax?"* - I'd look at the [existing Rust postgres driver](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/tree/master/postgres-protocol) for that. As mentioned, there already is a full client implementation in Rust for postgres. I'm not sure if I completely understand that crate, but it might be that [this here](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/master/postgres-protocol/src/message/backend.rs#L112) is what you are searching for. I might misunderstand it, though.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. For anyone else struggling there's a postgres-protocol package with utilities to help parse stuff like DataRows. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just simply take the response from a postgres server and parse it as UTF-8 text. The protocol is binary and defined [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html).

There's also no real need to implement this yourself, as there are already mature [postgres drivers for Rust](https://crates.io/crates/postgres).

If you want to do it anyway, you can take the [official implementation of the postgres Rust driver](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/master/postgres-protocol/src/message/backend.rs) as a reference. In your case, the message seems to start with a `ROW_DESCRIPTION_TAG`.

But again, if you aren't sure and simply want to use postgres, use the [existing drivers](https://crates.io/crates/postgres) instead. There's no need to re-implement the protocol by yourself.

I also recommend [`diesel`](https://diesel.rs/), which is a typesafe query builder for Rust that supports postgres. It makes interacting with a database even easier and more robust.